# PDFTron - perimeter and side lengths from area measurement

Tags: typescript, pdftron

1. Is it possible to get perimeter value in scale from polygon area measurement?
2. Is it possible to get any side length values of polygon area measurement in scale?

[Missing dimensions - example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg09y.png)

Comment: Have you tried using measurement annotation from https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/samples/advanced/#measurement-annotations?

Comment: Ye, I've got every measurement working and thats fine, but I want some additional values only from polygon area measurements.

Comment: So you don't have any idea on that question? Tell us what you think, you intuition on this problem at least.

Comment: Well, the only possible solution that I see is to calculate this by yourself. I mean you take the vertices of polygon, calculate distances and multiply it by scale factor, but haven't tried it yet.